# How to parse m3u in Dart

Tags: dart

I having difficult to sort all the details in the m3u file in Dart. There is no tutorial out there. Here the link for the m3u file:

https://iptv-org.github.io/iptv/languages/tha.m3u

Hope you can help, pls.

Comment: https://iptv-org.github.io/iptv/languages/tha.m3u

Comment: Have you looked at: https://pub.dev/packages/m3u ?

Comment: @julemand101 send it as an answer!

Comment: @julemand101 I don't know how to use, you know?

Comment: Read the documentation? It seems rather simple but without any description of what you want, it is difficult to give are specific example for you. https://pub.dev/documentation/m3u/latest/m3u/m3u-library.html

Comment: What I am trying to say is that I can make an example for you but you need to give a better description of what kind of result you want. Do you need to extract some data? When you say "sort all the details" what do you mean? Sort by title?

Comment: @julemand101 extract data

Comment: How much data? Do you just want the title and URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [m3u](https://pub.dev/packages/m3u) package to parse the file:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:m3u/m3u.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  final source = await File('tha.m3u').readAsString();
  final m3u = await M3uParser.parse(source);

  for (final entry in m3u) {
    print('Title: ${entry.title} Link: ${entry.link} Logo: ${entry.attributes['tvg-logo']}');
  }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Title: 13 Siam TV Link: http://203.154.83.176:1935/live/13wDt2b6g4/playlist.m3u8 Logo: https://i.imgur.com/fdopfeC.jpg
Title: 69 TV Link: https://edge1a.v2h-cdn.com/appt7/MediaOnline.stream_360p/chunklist_w559182369.m3u8 Logo: https://i.imgur.com/7KVr5UN.png
Title: 69 TV Link: https://edge1a.v2h-cdn.com/appt7/MediaOnline.stream_720p/chunklist.m3u8 Logo: https://i.imgur.com/7KVr5UN.png
Title: Amarin TV Link: https://www.doofree88.com/streaming/hd-amarin_720/index.m3u8 Logo: https://tv.guchill.com/images/img_tv/tv/ch1026.gif
Title: Bull & Chicken Showtime Link: https://1396402344.rsc.cdn77.org/LS-50041-SIN-23/tracks-v1a1/mono.m3u8 Logo: https://i.imgur.com/DIo2G4b.png
...
```

Can also be made like this if you want to download the file from a URL and parse it. I have made use of the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:m3u/m3u.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> main() async {
  final response =
      await http.get('https://iptv-org.github.io/iptv/languages/tha.m3u');
  final m3u = await M3uParser.parse(response.body);

  for (final entry in m3u) {
    print('Title: ${entry.title} Link: ${entry.link} Logo: ${entry.attributes['tvg-logo']}');
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm keep getting this error -> E/flutter (16571): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'images/kor.m3u' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: can you share your source code somewhere like GitHub

Comment: Yes because my code is an example of how to use the m3u package with a String input and not how to get the file. To get the string I just load the files I have downloaded manually from you link and placed together with the script running on a normal Dart VM (not flutter). But again, you question was about parsing a m3u file and not about getting the m3u file.

Comment: My example is the full code which you can run with a standard dart executable as long the m3u file is placed in the same directory.

Comment: Updated my answer with a solution which fetch the m3u file from the provided URL so it no longer requires the m3u file to be stored on disk.

Comment: nice, now it's work. Can I extract the logo url as well?

Comment: You're a saviour

Comment: Please accept the answer if you don't have more questions. :)